# SQL - JOIN not finding rows with no matches

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

**Server**: SQL Server 2008 R2
**Language**: T-SQL

I need to collect a list of updates installed on each machine. I don't have a problem, generally, with how it works now except I also need to see the machines where the total count is zero (0) or NULL.

Current query, which doesn't return machines where there are 0 matches. In other words, it is only returning rows where there is a match

```
SELECT 
    f_assettag, COUNT(DISTINCT f_updateinstalledID) AS f_totalupdatesinstalled 
FROM 
    tb_assets
INNER JOIN 
    tb_updatesinstalled ON f_updateinstalledmachine = f_assettag
GROUP BY 
    f_assettag
```

EDIT: This has been resolved. It should not have been using an "INNER" join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, bad post. I just realized now I was using an INNER join. I have changed it to a LEFT join and it works as-intended now.

Updated query:

```
SELECT 
    f_assettag, COUNT(DISTINCT f_updateinstalledID) AS f_totalupdatesinstalled 
FROM 
    tb_assets
LEFT JOIN 
    tb_updatesinstalled ON f_updateinstalledmachine = f_assettag
GROUP BY 
    f_assettag
```